# Breaking a promise chain (with multiple happy flows and single chain)

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

This question has been asked before but I wasn't satisfied with solutions like rejecting and handling in `catch` for breaking for a happy flow. I want to know if we can end up with multiple happy flows in a linear promise chain without rejecting (except in case of errors).

Here's my code sample:

```
const goStraight = (steps) => {
  return new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve(steps+2);
  });
};


const turnLeft = (steps) => {
  return new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve(++steps);
  });
};


const turnRight = (steps) => {
  return new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve(++steps);
  });
};

goStraight(0)
.then((total_steps_taken) => {
  if (total_steps_taken % 2 === 0) 
    return turnLeft(total_steps_taken);
  else 
    return null; // This is where I want to break the chain
})
.then((total_steps_taken) => {
  return turnRight(total_steps_taken);
}).then((total_steps_taken) => {
  console.log("Finished with Total Steps : "+total_steps_taken);
})
```

In the case that I start with `goStraight(1)` the code would flow in the `else` condition and this is when I want to break the chain.

Just want to know if it can be done without creating branches or using promise rejection.

Comment: so, you don't even want to show "total steps"?

Comment: Yes. Don't want to show that

Comment: seems rejecting is the "best" way

Comment: @JaromandaX I get your point but technically this is not an error case and in complex codes, differentiating between errors or ending of happy flows in catch will become a headache. What do you think?

Comment: You are hung up on something that you don't need to by hung up on.  A reject is a way to abort a promise chain up to the next `.catch()` handler.  You can abort the chain because of an error or you can abort for other reasons (non-errors, such as you are done or wish to skip some steps).  If you put everything in sequence in a chain with no other logic in that chain and no sub-chains, then the ONLY way to skip part of the chain is a reject.

Comment: You can also create sub-chains and use program logic (like `if` statements) to skip sub-chains without aborting.  But, that's not just a single linear chain.  If you insist on a single linear chain, then you have to use `reject()` to skip whole steps in the chain.  You can execute a step, but skip the code it would have run, but to do that you have to put `if` statements inside the step and you have to pass in some data that tells the `if` what to do.  As things stand now, you're making far too hypothetical case to advise very specifically.

Comment: To summarize, here are three of your may choices: 1) reject to skip to the next `.catch()`, 2) create sub-chains of promises that you can use logic to decide which ones to run or 3) put `if` logic inside each step and look at the data you are passing along to decide whether that step should run or not.

Comment: @jfriend00 Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other than using promise rejection, a possible approach to clean the code up could be to organize the happy paths into their own chains which get combined into a single chain.

In other words, every sequence of steps that should happen, well, sequentially, should be organized together.

In the particular snippet you provided, you always go right after you went left, so just make that an explicit chain that happens if the number of steps taken is even:

```
const happyPath = total_steps_taken => turnLeft(total_steps_taken)
  .then(turnRight)
  .then(logSteps);

goStraight(0).then(total_steps_taken => {
  if (total_steps_taken % 2 === 0) {
    return happyPath(total_steps_taken);
  }
});
```

Full example:

```js
const stepPromise = direction => x => {
  console.log(`going ${x} steps ${direction}`);
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve(x), 500);
  });
}

const turnLeft = stepPromise('left')
const turnRight = stepPromise('right');
const goStraight = stepPromise('straight');
const logSteps = steps => console.log(`steps taken: ${steps}`);

const happyPath = steps => turnLeft(steps)
  .then(turnRight)
  .then(steps => console.log(`Took ${steps} steps`));

const branchOrQuit = steps => {
  if (steps % 2 === 0) {
    console.log('going down the happy path');
    return happyPath(steps);
  }
  console.log('quitting');
}

const happyExample = () => {
  console.log('\n --- EVEN ---');
  return goStraight(2).then(branchOrQuit);
}


const sadExample = () => {
  console.log('\n --- ODD ---');
  return goStraight(1).then(branchOrQuit);
}

happyExample().then(sadExample);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to continue at any point when total steps taken is odd then you can wrap all your functions in a checks if the total steps is not an odd number:

```
const checkNotOdd = 
  fn                =>
  total_steps_taken =>
    (total_steps_taken%2===0)
      ? Promise.reject("no odd number of steps")
      : fn(total_steps_taken)

checkNotOdd(goStraight)(0)
.then(
  //not checking here, would otherwise reject
  turnLeft
  // checkNotOdd(turnLeft)
)
.then((total_steps_taken) => 
  checkNotOdd(turnRight)
).then(
    total_steps_taken => console.log("Finished with Total Steps : "+total_steps_taken),
    err => console.warn("Failed with:",err)
)
```